# Use std::copy to copy from random number distribution

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++98 I can use std::copy to copy from an input stream to a std::vector using iterator adapters.  Is there some way to do a similar thing from the new C++11 random number library?

What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 1024);
std::vector<int> col;
std::copy(std::adapter_type(dist), std::adapter_type(dist, 128), std::back_inserter(col));
```

Where the "end" iterator would have to have some way to limit how many numbers are inserted in the vector.  And, yes, I do know that I need some type of engine to make the distribution work.

Comment: I would have gone `std::vector<int> col(std::generator(dist, 128), std::generator());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) (which is not actually new):

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(col), 128, std::bind(dist, gen));
```

(Here `gen` is a suitable random number engine.)

Comment: Huh, not sure why that's an algorithm instead of an iterator.  I was looking at boost :/